# Complicated jquery syntax I don't understand

Tags: jquery, accordion

I only have a basic knowledge of jquery and I'm having trouble understanding how to read some code which I need to modify. Hopefully, I haven't pulled it too much out of context, but it comes amongst 500 lines of jquery code. The code in question is:

```
  // Expose in jQuery API
  $.fn.extend({
    collapse: function(options, scan) {
      var nodes = (scan) ? $("body").find("[data-collapse]") : $(this);
      return nodes.each(function() {
        var settings = (scan) ? {} : options,
          values = $(this).attr("data-collapse") || "";
        $.each(values.split(" "), function(i,v) {
          if(v) settings[v] = true;
        });
        new jQueryCollapse($(this), settings);
      });
    }
  });
```

There isn't much about this code I understand. While I'm familiar with ternary syntax using ? and :, I don't understand if this part is something else entirely:

```
var settings = (scan) ? {} : options, values =
$(this).attr("data-collapse") || "";
```

Also, what are the empty curly brackets doing? I did look around for jquery syntax documentation, but I didn't find explanations to what appears to me to be advanced coding. Can someone point me in the right direction?

(In case a little more background info is necessary, this comes from an accordion plugin for WordPress called PPM Accordion. The accordion.js file contains the code above. I've modified the html by inserting a checkbox into the subject headings that collapse, but the checkboxes can't be checked for some reason. Commenting out the code above restores the checkboxes, but it also stops the sections from collapsing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var value = a || b;

value = a if a == true

else value = b

So in your code the variable is set to the value of the data attribute 'collapse' when that value is not false. Incase it's false it will be set to a empty string ("").

Comment: Thanks seahorsepip. I'm starting to get it, but the thing I'm still struggling with is that it looks to me like **var settings = (scan) ? {} : options** is one line of code and **values = $(this).attr("data-collapse") || ""** is a second line, but why are they separated by a comma?

Comment: Variables can be set on multiple lines and end each with a semicolon(;) or on one line(written on 2 lines intepreted as one line) and seperated with a comma in javascript. Most of the time I only see the first syntax which I prefer and suggest myself.

Comment: Thanks again. It's making much more sense now. And for any others like me, with a weak grasp of jquery, I found out here [https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/817140-variable-initialization-curly-braces](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/817140-variable-initialization-curly-braces) that the empty curly brackets initialize a variable as a new object.

Comment: Indeed {} initializes an object and [] initializes an array. It's possible to put arrays into objects or objects into arrays :) Both objects and arrays have their benefits.